# I use node -v but did not get the real version

Tags: node.js, installation, version, nodes

As you can see, I have two different versions of node.js, what can I do when book ***node -v*** in cmd I get the real version is v17.2.0

[image]

[image: screenshot from cmd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple installations of node, check your PATH.

[image: path]

Also I'd recommend using NVS to manage node versions on your machine.

- [Node Version Switcher](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs)

```
nvs add 14
nvs add 17

nvs use 14
nvs use 17
```

Comment: In addition, I found an error in the environment because I type a PATH that contains Arabic, so I deleted this path and then wrote *nvs use 17* to work, and then I returned the path that contains Arabic words again